# How to create a "dynamic" forms - and store data and form design in two fields

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am making a system for at company that has a lot of field workers that need to fill out a lot of certificates at every job they do. We do this via a tablet pc running a mysql/php/apache system that syncs to the main server.

These certificates change a lot - so I get newer revisions all the time. And if I make this in a traditional database/php/html setup - I would be changing designs and databases forever, not to talk about handling revisions of certificate designs and data. (adding, removing fields)

I am looking for a way where I easily can design a form and store its design and data in one row (in two fields) - in my mysql database. So that when reading a specific row - I always have the correct design matched to its data I can merge together. This can be done via xforms - but the browser needs a plugin to do this. An xforms is tedious.

It is fairly easy to do with text fields only, but I need checkboxes, lists and so on....

Any brainstorming is appreciated.

Comment: I may have not grasped fully your question, do you want some sort of "modular" form fields you can piece together according to the different certificates? (ex cer.1 needs 3 input text and 1 checkbox, cer.2 needs 2 texts fields and 2 select and so on)

Comment: Yes - and then store the data generated by that. Because I must assume that the form is never the same I need to store the data and form side by side.

Answer (score 3):

What about using a NoSQL like MongoDB for storing the certifacates? Would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right you are especially looking for a way to save the user data to a database, as mentioned before you can change your your database engine to a NoSQL dbe or export the data to CSV, JSON, or use the php serialize() function.

If you want to have real fieldnames you can use multiple tables for storing the data. The main table only has the type of the certificate and the id of the real data in another table saving the data for a specific certificate (and maybe some general data, e.g. a timestamp).

This method isn't perfect and requires more PHP code and fetching similar data from multiple tables but it is the method I'd prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps use a form module from ZendFramework or the likes to generate a form, then serialize the object and store it to the database. Then you would get buildt in validation and filling that form with data from the database would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ValidForm it's a great opensource library for users handling forms. This does not just handle forms it handles:

- Validation
- Client Side Security
- Server Side Security
- Style
- Much more!

You cannot go wrong with it and most of all it's free and easy to use and I think it would be ideal for you!

http://validformbuilder.org/

Best of luck,
Tyler Moore

Answer (score 1):

try this.

Create a table with two fields as you said then use a csv to store your design and data in the two fields of the table.

For example

nameTxt,ageTxt,genderRdo,agreeChk
xxx,25,M,Yes

then you can easily explode this using

$csvExplode = explode(",",$fetchedData);

Better yet if you want styling info stored, make one more column and store the style info for each of the field in it.

hope this helps

Comment: I don't like the look of a "store in a store", but practically it could work.
If it has to be a traditional relational database, I would prefer a table with fieldnames and another with values related to the respective fieldname.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing the data in multidimensional arrays, then using php serialize() function to put it into the database?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with the following fields:

> 1. ID - PK/Auto Increment
> 2. FieldName
> 3. FieldType
> 4. Required (True/False)

Then you can simply store the values in a seperate table:

> 1. ID
> 2. FK_Field_ID - refers to the Fields Table

You could also potentially have a forms Table that refers to the Fields table.

Next I would suggest you build a fields class i.e. CreateTextInput, CreateNumberInput etc. I've done exactly this by overloading the methods. Sorry I cant share the code, it was for a client.

Hope this helps,
IgnitedCoder.com